# what permissions should i add in mainfest.xml

Tags: android, permissions

```
what permissions should i add in mainfest.xml of adroid studio for following app. Please help me. i am new developer.
```

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=aa.bb.waqas.myapplication&hl=en

tell me about all permissions that i need to add it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="aa1.bb.waqas.myapplication">
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="IELTS Preparation In One Day"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".splash">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".t1" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".t2" />
        <activity android:name=".t3" />
        <activity android:name=".t4" />
        <activity android:name=".t5" />
        <activity android:name=".t6" /><activity android:name=".t7" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: how should we know t that ?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />  try this permission in your manifest.

Answer (score 2):

As you shared the link of application, there are only two permissions are needed

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

and You may need to add more permissions as per your requirements.

Comment: but i also used 1) banner adds  2) interstitial adds 3) PDF files

Comment: no need of any extra permission except internet permission For banner add and interstitial adds.
if you are using storage for PDF like read or write so you have need to add following permissions :  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />